# C#/WPF: Save User Settings in Ressource file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, user-input

Is there any way to save user settings in a Ressource-File or such like this because I want that the user doesn't see e.g. the .xml-File.

Comment: You will need to expand your question and make it more detailed. What are you doing at the moment, can you show a code example? Where are you afraid the user will see the xml from?

Comment: At the moment I save the font of my programm in an XML file. But I don't like it because the user shouldn't see that file. And now I'm looking for any way to save it "intern".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend your applications .config file or resource files for application specific settings. This is the common way of doing things.

[WPF Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742538.aspx)

[ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this is to use a standard `.settings` file with settings set to `user` scope. While these files *are* stored as XML, they are hidden by default in the `AppData` folder of each user. In my opinion, any user that can work out where their settings file is stored is welcome to change them.

Please take a look at the [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) page on MSDN for full details.